# Call a function which is fetching an API and render the return values, problem with Promises

Tags: javascript, promise

In shoppingView.js I want to render a block for every 'item' in 'items', however I get a promise instead of a value from the function call, the format is json. How can I retrieve all the items from the array and render them?
---> Check the comment in ShoppingView render()

*I know about '.then()', 'async/await' but I'm not sure how to think when dealing with functions returning promises.. Can I force a function to returns a value instead of a promise and let the program wait for it when calling?*

I appreciate all help :)

Semi pseudo code..

## storeModel.js - Handling api calls etc.

```
class StoreModel {
  constructor() {
    this.items = [];
  } 

  getItems() {
    return this.items;
  }

  getItem(id) {
    const res = fetch(ENDPOINT + '/grocery/' + id + '/information/', {
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {
        "Host": ENDPOINT,
        "Key": API_KEY,
      }
    })
    .then(res => {
      if(res.ok) {
        console.log("SUCCESS");
        return res.json(); 
      } else {
        console.log("UNSUCCESSFUL");
        return res.json()
      }
    })
    .then({
        data => return data
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
    return res;
  }

  addItem(item) {
    this.items.push(item);
  }
}
```

## app.js

```
window.onload = function () {
  const cont = document.body.querySelector("#container");
  const model = new StoreModel();

  Promise.all([
     model.addItem(model.getItem(1)),
     model.addItem(model.getItem(2)),
     model.addItem(model.getItem(3)),
  ])
  .then(
    new HomeView(cont, model).render();
    new ShoppingView(cont, model).render();
  });
}
```

## shoppingView.js

```
class ShoppingView {
  constructor(container, model) {
    this.container = container;
    this.model = model;
  }

  render() {
    this.container.appendChild(document.createElement('h3').textContent = "Items";
    var div = this.container.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));

    /* GET THE VALUE OF items HERE */ 

    /* I'VE TRIED ********************************
    var items = this.model.getItems();
    ----> item.title etc, is undefined
    **********************************************/
    for(let item of items {
      div.appendChild(document.createElement('img')).setAttribute('src', item.image);
      div.appendChild(document.createElement('h4')).textContent = item.title;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `getItem` method is full of syntax errors. I assume it's correct in your actual code? `app.js` is also wrong... It's difficult to make suggestions if we don't know what the actual code looks like.

Comment: Ok, sorry it's added now. Pretty sure it's not my problem though

Comment: `.then( new HomeView(cont, model).render(); new ShoppingView(cont, model).render();});` is still wrong. `.then` expects to be passed a function. If you do that then it should work (although I would structure it differently). *edit:* Actually it won't work since you are never assigning to `this.item` in `storeModel`. Is `getDish` meant to append to `this.items`? Is it supposed to call `addToBag`? I think the problem is less about promises and more about you not passing/setting the data correctly.

Comment: Sorry for that.. So, I want to instantiate the classes after assigning the model its data. Yes I might be stuck already here

Answer (score 1):

storeModel.js

```
// remove syntactically incorrect and redundant handler
.then({ data => return data }) // should be .then(data => data) (no curly braces or return)
```

`model.getItem` always returns a `Promise` which will need to be resolved before the value is accessible, ie.

```
model.getItem(id).then(item => {
  // do something with item... eg.
  model.addItem(item);
});
```

The value you are passing in to `model.addItem` is a promise, not an `item`, so you are populating your items list with promises. `model.addItem` returns `undefined`, so in `app.js` `Promise.all` is trying to resolve `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`.  Since you don't care about the result of `Promise.all`, consider this approach:

app.js

```
Promise.all([1, 2, 3].map(id => {
  return model.getItem(id).then(item => model.addItem(item))
})).then((items) => {
  new HomeView(cont, model).render();
  new ShoppingView(cont, model).render();
});
```

the result will be `[undefined, undefined, undefined]` but you don't need it anyway, since the items have been added to `model.items` already.

Comment: Yes thank you, but the problem now is to render the actual values in shoppingView.js, how do I call the function correctly from that file with only the model reference?